# Add registry key through code

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, registry

I'm trying to add a `registry key` through my code on the startup of the program. I'm completely new to this and I don't know how to (and couldn't search for) but I have tried with this code:

```
RegistryKey HTML5Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

if (HTML5Key != null)
{
    HTML5Key.SetValue("mybrowser.exe", "270f", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    HTML5Key.Close();
}
```

But it simply does nothing. What am I doing wrong? I have admin rights. I have tried to debug it but I can't even get inside the `if bracket`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `OpenSubKey` to open key in registry, so if specified key is not exist in registry it will return null. That is why your code is not working. Check whether sub key exist or not and then open it for writting.

One more mistake in your code you want to open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` sub key so write code as follows

```
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true)
```

Comment: I tried with `HTML5Key.OpenSubKey("browser.exe", true);` with no success, it gives me and exception error this time. Should I declare it in any other way?

Comment: I modified my answer check now.

Comment: Of course I wrote wrong now... `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is the one I want to open.

Comment: Tried now with `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);`It is returning the vaule `null`.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, portions of the registry entries are stored separately for 32-bit application and 64-bit applications and mapped into separate logical registry views. If you are not using 64bit Windows PC then use `"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION"`

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I cannot get the registry to be other than `null` :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for write the value in registry.

```
private string _subKey = "Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";

private string SubKey
{
    get { return _subKey; }
    set { _subKey = value; }
}

private RegistryKey _baseRegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine;

private RegistryKey BaseRegistryKey
{
    get { return _baseRegistryKey; }
    set { _baseRegistryKey = value; }
}

 private bool WriteDbToRegistry(string keyName, object value)
{
    try
    {
        var rk = BaseRegistryKey;
        var sk1 = rk.CreateSubKey(SubKey);
        if(sk1 != null) sk1.SetValue(keyName.ToUpper(), value);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please run your App as Administrator.", "Administrator");
        return false;
    }
}

 bool results = WriteDbToRegistry("Keyname", "2710");
```

and get value from registry..

```
   public string GetRegistryValue()
    {
        var rk = BaseRegistryKey;
        var sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(SubKey);
            try
            {
                return (string)sk1.GetValue("Keyname");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "some message");
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should this be inserted? I can't find the right way.

Comment: above i have given you two method for write value to registry and get value from registry..you can add wherever you want..

Comment: Thanks, I will look through your answer when I get home.

Comment: I tried to use your code but I cannot seem to get it to work. If i put it under `InitializeComponent();`, I get tons of errors. If I put it where my handlers are, the code does nothing. Also, I do not understand the purpose of the line `bool results = WriteDbToRegistry("Keyname", "2710");` could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

I put this together with minor changes to the code previously given by JasRaj to create the registry entry:

```
private string _subKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION";
private string SubKey
{
    get { return _subKey; }
    set { _subKey = value; }
}

private RegistryKey _baseRegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine;  

private RegistryKey BaseRegistryKey
{
    get { return _baseRegistryKey; }
    set { _baseRegistryKey = value; }
}

 private bool WriteDbToRegistry(string keyName, object value)
{
    try
    {
        var rk = BaseRegistryKey;
        var sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(SubKey,true); //true is required for making it writable
        if (sk1 != null)
        {
            sk1.SetValue(keyName, value,RegistryValueKind.DWord); //dword,qword 
            rk.Close();
            sk1.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            rk.Close();
            sk1.Close();
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

 public string GetRegistryValue(string keyname)
 {
     var rk = BaseRegistryKey;
     var sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey(SubKey);
     try
     {
         return sk1.GetValue(keyname).ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error");
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- You likely don't have permissions to write to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- You are not writing to the right location and an invalid value is used

Your problem is that you are writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and you most likely don't have permissions to write there under a normal user account. Unless you are an Administrator and running under elevated rights you can't write there. However, for what you are trying to do luckily you don't need to write the HKLM, but you can write to the HKCU registry which **is allowed**.

Also the "270F" should be a number not a string so `0x270F` without quotes should be used.

The following code is what I use in one of my applications to set browser emulation:

```
using (var rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",true))
{
    dynamic value = rk.GetValue("MarkdownMonster.exe");
    if (value == null)
        rk.SetValue(exename, (uint) 11001, RegistryValueKind.DWord);                    
}
```